# Two bar charts side by side with double y lable

Tags: matlab

I want to plot a bar chart [MAT_LAB(:,2), MAT_LAB(:,3)] in single figure with double y-lable and range.

```
MAT_LAB=[ 1 4210 0.9915;
          2 4225  0.9951;
          3 4201  0.9894]
bar(MAT_LAB(:,2),'stacked','BarWidth',0.3);
hold;
bar(MAT_LAB(:,3),'stacked','BarWidth',0.3);
```

It is not working.Range of y1 is 0-4500. Range of y2 is 0-1.

Comment: define "not working".  Your `y1` and `y2` are very different ranges, so how are you going to show them on the same chart? Do you want to scale one to the other? Have two different y-axes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with [`plotyy`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plotyy.html) as follows:

```
delta = .2; %// adjust as needed
plotyy(MAT_LAB(:,1)-delta, MAT_LAB(:,2),...
       MAT_LAB(:,1)+delta, MAT_LAB(:,3),...
       @(x,y) bar(x,y, 'b', 'stacked', 'BarWidth', 0.3),...
       @(x,y) bar(x,y, 'r', 'stacked', 'BarWidth', 0.3));
```

Notes:

- `delta` is used so that the two sets of bars are distinguised by displacing them horizontally.
- The two [anonymous functions](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) passed to `plotyy` control the actual plotting for each set of *x*, *y* values. You can specify `bar` options there. Using *two* anonymous functions lets you specify different options (such as color in my example).

[image]